# Should formulaic prayers/slogans be allowed?

Tags: support

This is not obviously a site to promote any religion, let alone any sects.

some posters include prayers/slogans in their posts like "Jai Shree Ram" and so forth.

Is there an official policy on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any salutations (*eg: Namaste, Hello*), slogans, requests (*eg: Someone please help*) etc are extraneous and should be removed. It is best in my opinion to keep only the relevant part of the question.

Reference: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Though very old posts shouldn't be edited just to remove such salutations, slogans, requests, etc.

Comment: Here is the [link to back this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/196352). Although, I think removing this site specific salutations or greetings are bound to one's religious sentiments/believes. Removing such might hurt that individual's feelings. I would say it is not such a level of problem which need a fix anytime soon. So, leave it as it is maybe?

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks for the link. Though I don't agree with it, I think you should write an answer based on *"although, I think....leave it as it is maybe?"* It is a very good point still.

Comment: Yes, there should be no discrimination between the salutations/greetings. Looks like we can request cmods to take them out automatically.